# MVC4 Razor On Accessing Multiple Model Classes on Single View Giving Error On Various Elements

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am having a `Shared Layout` for login. For login I am having a `LoginViewModel` for `username`,`password`,`returnurl` & `isRemember`. I having another model for `userSaltValue`. I want to get user salt value at the client side in hidden field on page load, which I am getting currently on button click at server side. On using both models it's giving me error for above parameters. How should I do that?

**Shared Layout:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head></head>

<body class="bg-gradient-primary">
  @RenderBody()   
</body>
</html>
```

**Login.cshtml:**

```
@model ROMvcApplication.Models.LoginVM
@model ROMvcApplication.Models.UserSalt
```

**LoginVM.cs**

```
namespace ROMvcApplication.Models
{
    public class LoginVM
    {
        public string Username { get; set; }

        public string Password { get; set; }

        public string ReturnURL { get; set; }

        public bool isRemember { get; set; }

    }
}
```

**UserSalt.cs:**

```
namespace ROMvcApplication.Models
{
    public class UserSalt
    {
        public string saltvalue { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have two different types for the same model:

```
@model ROMvcApplication.Models.LoginVM
@model ROMvcApplication.Models.UserSalt
```

After all, when you reference the `Model` variable in that view, which would you expect to see?

You *can* however add your field to the model you're already using:

```
public class LoginVM
{
    public string Username { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }

    public string ReturnURL { get; set; }

    public bool isRemember { get; set; }

    public string saltvalue { get; set; }
}
```

*Or*, if you don't want to change that model for whatever reason, you can create a composite model for this view:

```
public class LoginWithSaltVM
{
    public LoginVM Login { get; set; }

    public string saltvalue { get; set; }
}
```

Basically, you have complete freedom to create and modify your classes to suit your needs.